# Difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference?

Tags: go, reference

I'm new here, I'm learning the programming language Go. I previously departed from an object-oriented programming language, so I'm a bit confused when it comes to pass-by-value and pass-by-reference topics

Please help to explain the difference between the two and examples of each programming language that uses the method. Thank You

Comment: The distinction is irrelevant for learning Go because Go doesn't have references. [Everything is passed by value](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Calls). Function arguments and return values work just like assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass something by value, you're passing the value the object represents. In contrast, if you pass something by reference, you're passing a reference to the object itself.

For example, take this sample variable a:

```
var a = "test"
```

Passing a by value means passing "test". If you modify what you passed, it will not affect a. 
However, if you pass a by reference, you're passing a. This means that what you passed is a reference to the original variable a directly, and modifying it modifies a as well.

Comment: okay. I'm starting to understand it, I'll improve my lessons on go little by little

Comment: As fairly noted in the comment to your post, you don't even need to concentrate on that very much in Go. Everything is always passed by value. You might need to understand though that there are types often called "reference types" (but this terminology is not favored by the Go team if I understand correctly) that are/include a pointer. But then again that pointer is copied and passed by value